# How to return a date format similar to 7-Feb-2012 using TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datepart

Using TSQL, How to return a date with a format similar to "7-Feb-2012"?

this returns the day:

```
SELECT DATEPART(d, getdate())
```

this returns the year:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())
```

How to return the month name?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to?  In general it is advised to separate data and presentation.  Return the Date in it's native type (which does not have a format, uses fewer bytes, and is easiet to manipulate) and format it in your client.

Comment: I asked a question, don't worry why. it's about an import from one database to another.

Comment: "Why" often matters.  Often questions are asked where following the answer leads you into future problems.  Separation (if possible, and normally it is) of data and presentation gives a lot of flexibility.  Passing dates as string leads to unexpected behaviour (localisation, settings, etc) and makes debugging significantly harder.  I'm only trying to be more helpful, and not aiding you in a potential mistake that I've had to deal with in the past ;)  *[I didn't down-vote, and would say it's grossly undeserved.]*

Comment: William, don't be snippy. Why is often important to solving the real problem not just the one that was asked. @Dems is right, it is often more efficient to do this kind of manipulation at the application level.

Comment: that' generally true and that generally helps resolving issues and proposing new approaches but it doesn't matter here. if it had mattered I would have detailed. perhaps I should have explicitly written, please dont' ask why as that wouldn't help answering this question! ;)

Comment: @William - I reckon just explaining yourself to Dems instead of being snippy would've been sufficient :P. Hope my answer has helped anyway.

Comment: @Curt, thanks yeah that was the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will give you the format like "14-Feb-2012":

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') AS [dd-Mon-YYYY]
```

---

If you just want the month name, you can do:

```
select DATENAME(m, getdate())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),106)
```